# Substring in Google BigQuery

Tags: date, substring, google-bigquery

If I have a Date parameter such as: 
03. Mar at 5:00pm PST

and I only need to break it down by date so that my end result is:
03. Mar

how can I achieve that?
Is there a substring equivalent syntax in Google BigQery? Or maybe a date/time function to show only date and ignore the time?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this a string manipulation question? Then the answer would be getting the LEFT() 2 characters of that string.

If this is a date manipulation question:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP('2014-03-03 05:00:00')
2014-03-03 05:00:00 UTC 

SELECT DATE(TIMESTAMP('2014-03-03 05:00:00'))
2014-03-03

SELECT DAY(TIMESTAMP('2014-03-03 05:00:00'))
3
```